Is the involution centralizer in the Held group a split extension
According to the ATLAS of Finite groups, the centralizer of a 2B element in the sporadic Held group is 21+6.L3(2). According to the introductory section "How to read this ATLAS: Information about subgroups and their structure," this notation denotes any group extension, without specifying whether or not the extension splits. But the ATLAS specifically says that the centralizer of an involution is isomorphic to that of M24 and L5(2), and the extensions definitely split in these groups, so I am confused why the ATLAS uses generic extension notation.
I have briefly looked at Held's original paper, and I seem to remember it says that the extension does split, but I have not read this paper fully. I also know that the subgroup 21+6.L3(2) is inside the subgroup 21+24.Co1 of the Monster; more specifically, it is the L3(2) group that arises in the Suzuki chain. I know that 21+24.Co1 itself does not split, but I do not know if it becomes a split extension under the subgroup 21+6.L3(2).
This is what I understand. My ultimate question is, is the subgroup 21+6.L3(2) of He a split extension?

I just did a computation in Magma, and it splits, with three conjugacy classes of complements. I don't suppose there is any particular reason why they didn't specify it in the notation.

I did the same computation, and got the same result as Derek Holt.
